# doNothing method does not work with void static method

Tags: unit-testing, powermock

I am assigned to add unit test code coverage to a 15 years old legacy project which is not using IoC and 0 unit test. I am not allowed to refactor the code since it works perfect fine on production, management does not want other teams get involved for refactoring such as QA testing, etc.

Service class has a `performService` method has following code

```
public void performService(requestMessage, responseMessage) {
        UserAccount userAccount = requestMessage.getUserAccount();
        GroupAccount groupAccount = requestMessage.getGroupAccount();
        Type type = requestMessage.getType();
        StaticServiceCall.enroll(userAccount, groupAccount, type);
        response.setStatus(Status.SUCCESS);
}
```

This `StaticServiceCall.enroll` method is calling remote service. My unit test is

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StaticServiceCall.class)
public class EnrollmentServiceTest {

@Test
public void testPerformService() {      
    mockStatic(StaticServiceCall.class);
    doNothing().when(StaticServiceCall.enroll(any(UserAccount.class), any(GroupAccount.class), any(Type.class)));
    service.performService(requestMessage, responseMessage);
    assertEquals("Enrollment should be success, but not", Status.SUCCESS, response.getStatus);
}
```

Eclipse complains with `The method when(T) in the type Stubber is not applicable for the arguments (void)`

Eclipse stops complain if test code change to

```
mockStatic(StaticServiceCall.class);
doNothing().when(StaticServiceCall.class);
StaticServiceCall.enroll(any(UserAccount.class), any(GroupAccount.class), any(Type.class));
service.performService(requestMessage, responseMessage);
assertEquals("Enrollment should be success, but not", Status.SUCCESS, response.getStatus);
```

Test case failed with `UnfinishedStubbingException`. I am using powermock 1.6.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a misconception on your end. You think that you need to say that `doNothing()` should *do nothing*.

That is not necessary! As these lines

```
@PrepareForTest(StaticServiceCall.class) ... and 
mockStatic(StaticServiceCall.class);
```

are sufficient already.

You want to prevent the "real" content of that static method to run when the method is invoked during your test. And that is what `mockStatic()` is doing.

In other words: as soon as you use mockStatic() the **complete** implementation of the real class is *wiped*. You only need to use when/then/doReturn/doThrow in case you want to happen something *else* than **nothing**.

Meaning: just remove that whole doNothing() line!

Answer (score 1):

@GhostCat - Thank you for your answer, it solved problem, my misconception is coming from this test case

```
@Test
public void testEnrollmentServiceSuccess() {
    RequestMessage requestMessage = new RequestMessage();
    requestMessage.setName("ENROLL");
    ResponseMessage responseMessage = new ResponseMessage();

    EnrollmentService mockService = mock(EnrollmentService.class);
    mockService.performService(any(RequestMessage.class), any(ResponseMessage.class));

    mockStatic(ClientManager.class);
    when(ClientManager.isAuthenticated()).thenReturn(true);

    ServiceImpl service = new ServiceImpl();
    service.performService(requestMessage, responseMessage);
    verify(mockService).performService(any(RequestMessage.class), any(ResponseMessage.class));
}
```

Here is the code snippet of `ServiceImpl` class based name of the request message calling different service class

```
    public void performService(RequestMessage request, ResponseMessage response) {
    try {
        if (request == null) {
            throw new InvalidRequestFormatException("null message");
        }
        if (!ClientManager.isAuthenticated()) {
            throw new ServiceFailureException("not authenticated");
        }
        // main switch for known services
        if ("ENROLL".equals(request.getName())) {
            service = new EnrollmentService();
            service.performService(request, response);
        } else if ("VALIDATE".equals(request.getName())) {
        ...
```

Although the test passed,real implementation in `EnrollmentService` got called and exceptions thrown due to barebone RequestMessage object, then I googled out doNothing, thanks again for your clarification